# Can I improve this query with an inner join?

Tags: postgresql

I have this query and it works fine, but it is not that easy to read and I was wondering if it could be improved somehow, perhaps with a join. Currently, I need to manually specify all but one of the columns (specifically id_template) on the assets table but I'd rather join the subquery straight over the top of the id field. I cannot work out how to do that though, is it even possible?

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT to_json(template) AS template
    FROM (
        SELECT *, (
            SELECT json_agg(to_json(fields)) as fields
            FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM public.fields
                WHERE id_template = templates.id
            ) fields
        )
        FROM public.templates    
        WHERE templates.id = assets.id_template
    ) template
)
FROM public.assets
WHERE assets.id = $1
```

As requested here is the data returned from the above query in JSON form, please excuse the test data with weird names etc.

```
[
 {
   "name": "egnf",
   "data": "{}",
   "id": "8358b1f0-3935-4104-92a5-0c6efdecc747",
   "id_organisation": "b963890b-d956-48d3-8fa4-2f6d70d87bd7",
   "id_template": "7958b0ef-f9cf-4861-b478-40072ca58ad3",
   "created_date": "2019-01-24 16:20:53.744976+00",
   "last_modified_date": "2019-01-28 16:47:59.108746+00",
   "last_modified_by": "3138ced1-33be-4969-94f8-5b63914452d5",
   "template":     {  
       'name':'mod test',
       'data':{  

       },
       'type':'asset',
       'id_organisation':'b963890b-d956-48d3-8fa4-2f6d70d87bd7',
       'id':'7958b0ef-f9cf-4861-b478-40072ca58ad3',
       'last_modified_date':'2019-01-22T17:13:57.973411+00:00',
       'last_modified_by':'3138ced1-33be-4969-94f8-5b63914452d5',
       'created_date':'2019-01-15T14:17:49.831689+00:00',
       'fields':[  
          {  
             'name':'test field',
             'data':None,
             'configuration':'',
             'id_organisation':'b963890b-d956-48d3-8fa4-2f6d70d87bd7',
             'id_template':'7958b0ef-f9cf-4861-b478-40072ca58ad3',
             'id_format':'85b89541-0c57-4bb2-97e8-86fc4efbc568',
             'id':'e5f16e97-2843-4383-80ef-08baf6b04311',
             'last_modified_date':'2019-01-22T17:13:58.446235+00:00',
             'last_modified_by':'3138ced1-33be-4969-94f8-5b63914452d5',
             'created_date':'2019-01-21T12:58:15.821335+00:00'
          },
          {  
             'name':'third field',
             'data':None,
             'configuration':'',
             'id_organisation':'b963890b-d956-48d3-8fa4-2f6d70d87bd7',
             'id_template':'7958b0ef-f9cf-4861-b478-40072ca58ad3',
             'id_format':'66276b7f-64bb-4116-8dfc-28a300d0e34b',
             'id':'1a961240-98ec-45e0-93b2-099ce48cc521',
             'last_modified_date':'2019-01-22T17:13:58.447973+00:00',
             'last_modified_by':'3138ced1-33be-4969-94f8-5b63914452d5',
             'created_date':'2019-01-21T14:14:29.235838+00:00'
          }
       ]
    }
 }
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have 5 nested queries, so my guess is that yes, you can probably do without some of them.  But, please include some sample data which explains what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Check WITH statements. It is meant for simply queries as you mentioned. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-with.html

Comment: Sample data added as requested, will also look into with statements

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky it seems. I'm fairly new to postgres myself. Since there isn't any data to test my query on I have to submit it like that.

Your query contains some so-called *correlated subqueries*, i.e. when there is a subquery in the `select`-statement of the outer query, and they are linked via a `where`-clause. As far as I know they can be replaced by left joins. So that's what I did. Hope it works. If not, maybe it still gave you a new idea.

```
SELECT assets.*, templates.* , json_agg(to_json(fields)) as field
FROM public.assets
LEFT JOIN public.templates  
ON templates.id = assets.id_template
LEFT JOIN public.fields
ON fields.id_template = templates.id
WHERE assets.id = $1
GROUP BY (all variables till json_agg);
```

Comment: Something like this would be awesome because it is so much smaller. But I don't want everything on one row, this query is a return for a GraphQL API and template is a separate object from asset hence it returning as a property of the parent in the JSON, rather then being part of the parent. I have also just noticed that the sample data is incomplete, editing question now.

Comment: I didn't check if that is really the same, but the general idea is correct, so +1.